# Mongodb start failure in Centos 7

Tags: mongodb, centos7, wiredtiger

I get the following error when trying to start mongodb in Centos 7.

> 2020-10-11T18:50:38.859+0100 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (22) [1602438638:858979][8880:0x7f52dd7f4e80], WT_SESSION.open_cursor: 'table:_mdb_catalog' cannot be used until all column groups are created: Invalid argument
> 2020-10-11T18:50:38.859+0100 I -        [initandlisten] Invariant failure: ret resulted in status BadValue: 22: Invalid argument at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_session_cache.cpp 113
> 2020-10-11T18:50:38.859+0100 I -        [initandlisten]

The complete log file can be seen [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ji8A9h_9n-b5Mb2m1UiZEqDKIriRYEAY/view?usp=sharing).

Could someone please help me with this?